# Installing Apache Solr on Windows WAMP Server

Tags: php, solr, wampserver

I tried to install Apache Solr on WAMP server (in Windows) and I succeeded but the problem was that I couldn't use the PHP Solr library on this environment. The error I keep getting is:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_solr.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0.
```

I've downloaded, included and activated the dll file containing the PHP Solr library but this error keeps comming.

PHP version: 5.4.12
Wampserver version: 2.4

Comment: Did you install Tomcat, Jetty, or Resin as well? you dont mention them!

Comment: yes, I have; I even tried with the Bitnami pack.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to make sure **JAVA** is installed on your windows machine; if not, make sure to download it from here https://www.java.com/en/download/
2. Download **Apache Solr** library from http://lucene.apache.org/solr/mirrors-solr-latest-redir.html
   (to download older version go to https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/)
3. Extract downloaded **Apache Solr** archive (i.e. in `C:\wamp\apache-solr-4.0.0`)
4. If you're setting up Solr to work with Drupal, you need to copy some additional files to `C:\wamp\apache-solr-4.0.0\example\solr\collection1` **[optional]**
5. Launch Windows Command Prompt (to launch RUN press *win+R* on your keyboard, then type "cmd" without the quotes, and click OK)
6. In Command Prompt window; change directory to **Apache Solr** example folder location, i.e. 
   `cd c:\wamp\apache-solr-4.0.0\example\`
7. Also, in Command Prompt; type the following command `java -jar start.jar`

   > *NOTE: Command Prompt should be kept open since Solr service is running. If you close it the service will stop.*
8. This will start jetty webserver and deploy **Solr** automatically
9. Now you can access **Solr** GUI from browser by going to `http://localhost:8983/solr`